# microservice for kubernetes that can start the container on attempt to login

Tags: kubernetes

I want to know whether their exist a microservice or project which can help me with my containers. What I want is basically start the container only when someone try to login inside that container. SHut the container down if it is halt for more than 30 min.I am not sure if this is even possible or not. Please help me if you have any idea.

Answer (score 0):

If by "login" you mean receive a request, then the closest to what you look for is actually FaaS approach (Function as a Service). There are couple contenders in this scope on kube market at the moment, most prominent I know of are [Funktion](https://funktion.fabric8.io/), [Fission](http://fission.io/) and [Kubeless](https://kubeless.io)